# How to add a class to a new row in a jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, addclass

How can I add a class to the row I'm adding in the datatable?

If not possible, how can I use `fnRowCallback` or `fnDrawCallback` to change the class?

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "bSortClasses": false,
  "sDom":'T<"clear">',
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"lfr>t<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"ip>',
  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {

    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    oSettings.aoData[iDisplayIndex].nTr.className = "gradeX odd";
  }
});
```

*The above code is giving me an error.*

this is how I add the row:

```
oTable.fnAddData(arr);
```

Comment: doubt it'll really help, but done. I've tried many other things, but without results.

Comment: or is there a way i can simply add an html row, to the datatable via the datatables functions

Answer (score 19):

Try changing your `fnRowCallback` to the following:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
  nRow.className = "gradeX odd";
  return nRow;
}
```

You can refer to the [offical documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) to further understanding this  callback function.

Comment: Best solution I found.  I wanted to add a class to a specific column instead of the row.
 $($(nRow).children()[1]).attr('class', 'status-indicator');

Answer (score 9):

You can add the classname in your data itself as described in the documentation.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html

use **DT_RowId** for adding id for any row
use **DT_RowClass** for adding class for any row
use **DT_RowData** for adding html5 data object to any row

eg:

"data": [
    {
      **"DT_RowId"**: "row_5",
      "first_name": "Airi",
      "last_name": "Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "start_date": "28th Nov 08",
      "salary": "$162,700"
    }]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var id = aData[0];
            $(nRow).attr("id",id);
            if ( jQuery.inArray(aData[0], gaiSelected) != -1 )
            {
                $(nRow).addClass('row_selected');
            }
            return nRow;
}
```

For adding row to datatable try this code from :

http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

```
/* Global var for counter */
var giCount = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        giCount+".1",
        giCount+".2",
        giCount+".3",
        giCount+".4" ] );

    giCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Official documentation says:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .rows.add( [
        new Pupil( 43 ),
        new Pupil( 67 ),
        new Pupil( 102 )
    ] )
    .draw()
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .addClass( 'new' );
```

Please read: [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add())

Comment: This code is for multiple row look at mine for single row.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable( {"fnInitComplete": after_init} );
} );
function after_init(){
    $("#table_id tbody tr").addClass("gradeA");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var r = t.row.add( [
    ....
] ).node();
$(r).css({"color":"red"});
```

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted, this solves the problem (except it's adding inline CSS)
To add a class using this technique just change $(r).css to $(r).addClass('class');

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation this work for me:

```
var my_dataTable = $('#my-table').DataTable();
my_dataTable.row.add( [
                'Hello',
                'Hello2',
                'Hello3',
                'Hello4'
            ] ).draw().nodes().to$().addClass("my_class");
```

Answer (score -4):

Alright, perhaps I'm not understanding exactly what your question is, but if you were just adding the row, why not set the class before you add it? Like this, somewhat sloppy, example:

```
jQuery("<tr />")
  .html(your_var_containing_the_interior_dom)
  .addClass("yourClass")
  .appendTo(jQuery("#yourTable"))
```