# Add row id/row data with multidimensional array formatted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

The jQuery DataTables plugin supports [arrays of objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) as well as [arrays of arrays](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html).  From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26334713/749227) I can see that if the object format is used, there are reserved keys that will be handled by the plugin.

I need to use the array of arrays format to keep the data sent over the wire as small as possible; sending the keys many times can greatly increase the response payload.

How do I do things like adding data to a row that needs to be used programmatically later on if I'm using the array data format?

Comment: Have you considered serverside processing so you only request the data you need and only deal with a page at a time?  This way you could use the Array of objects data format which fully supports this.  I put this as a comment since it is just a suggestion I just haven't run into a case where my data was small enough to still process everything client side but large enough where the Array of objects method had enough overhead to matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom data as JSON-encoded string as one of the array elements.

Then you can use [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option to define a callback function that will be called when `TR` element is created. Functions receives `TR` node and full data as arguments so you can perform necessary manipulation with the row as needed.

Comment: Hm - that definitely works.  And I can tack on "extra columns" in the JSON and consume those in the createdRow callback.  Still, it's nice to have convention-over-configuration.  I'd like not to have to write boilerplate callbacks every time I use the plugin.  I submitted a request on the github repo: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/892

Comment: the drawCallback is another option.  It fires only once per completed draw so if you manipulation is faster or lends it self to processing all rendered rows at once you could hook into this instead.